# A given Pod (as defined by a UID) is never "rescheduled" explanation quote in k8s documentation

Tags: kubernetes

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-lifetime

"A given Pod (as defined by a UID) is never "rescheduled" to a different node; instead, that Pod can be replaced by a new, near-identical Pod, with even the same name if desired, but with a different UID."

I am wondering the explanation in the document.

1. "A given Pod (as defined by a UID) is never "rescheduled" to a different node -> does it mean in case pod restart by kubelet in worker node
2. that Pod can be replaced by a new, near-identical Pod, with even the same name if desired, but with a different UID. -> i am not sure which case in real life and how i can simulate and check it.

i try to create fail pod

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-crash
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: fail
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'sleep 30; exit 1;']`
```

and using

```
kubectl get pod test-crash -o=jsonpath='{.metadata.uid}'
```

i didn't see pod'uid which is different.

Answer (score 0):

Once a Pod is scheduled on a Node, it is never rescheduled.

In your example, the Pod always fails, but a Pod's default restart policy is to restart on failure.  When it restarts, it is still the same Pod, so it still runs on the same Node.

Let's say, hypothetically, that you could log into the actual machine running the Node directly, and shut down the system as root.  Kubernetes on the whole can deal with this case reasonably gracefully.  To quote [the Kubernetes documentation cited at the top of the question](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-lifetime), though:

> If a Pod is scheduled to a node that then fails, the Pod is deleted....

The other answer to your question is that **you should never directly create Pods**.  In normal use you'll use a higher-level object: a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) in most cases, but a Job if the process expects to complete and exit normally, or a StatefulSet if the process needs persistent storage.

Let's say you wrap this in a Deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-crash
spec:
  # replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      test: crash
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        test: crash
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fail
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'sleep 30; exit 1;']`
```

I've commented out the `replicas: 1` as a Deployment's default, but it's important here.  The Deployment ensures that one Pod always exists that matches the template Pod spec.

This behavior can match up to the two cases we described before.  If the container exits, the same Pod still exists, and keeps running.  But if the Node fails, the cluster will delete the Pod; then the Deployment controller will see that zero Pods exist where it wants one, and it will create a new one.  That's the "replaced with a new, near-identical Pod" case that you quote in the question.

Comment: as your explanation i understood what happen in case using deployment controller and node fail -> create a new pod with different pod uid. But "A given Pod (as defined by a UID) is never "rescheduled" to a different node" how can we explain about never rescheduled, to a different node. These words in k8s's document that makes me confuse.

Comment: A given Pod (as defined by a UID) -> running pod and the quotes above can understand as following "A running Pod can never be "rescheduled" to a different node as Kubernetes does not support live migration of pods from one host to another. You can always create a new identical pod."